# Get name of the user who used Slash (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

I got problem with getting a username of the user who used Slash.

```py
    author = slash.username

    print(author)
```

I'm using **discord_slash** library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide any code, but you should be able to get it how you would normally. Using `ctx.author`